# Please Guide to Loop through a DataFrame while Pushing to Firebase

Tags: python, pandas, firebase, dataframe, firebase-realtime-database

I have a CSV file of data's which I want to push to Firebase using Python. The CSV has two columns `title` and `description` . I am `successful in pushing the title columns`, but unable to figure out how to push the description column as well.

This is my code :

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_data.csv')
mylist.append(df)
ref = db.reference('testnode')
for item in df['title'] : 
    ref.push().set({
        'title' : item,
        'description' : 'description here'
    })
```

This is the Output :

[please check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUS1Q.png)

As you can see, the description key is hardcoded as : `description here`

How can i write the description to Firebase in the same way im writing the title values ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code just reading the title to read the rest you need to provide column name.

```
from csv import DictReader
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
with open('csv_data.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_dict_reader = DictReader(read_obj)
    for row in csv_dict_reader:
        ref.push().set({
            'title' : row['title'],
            'description' : row['description']
        })
```

For Specific [Panda library](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows() : 
    ref.push().set({
        'title' : row['title'],
        'description' : row['description']
    })
```

Comment: getting Erro:     'title' : row['title'],
KeyError: 'title'

Comment: @Sainita there is different library i am using if you can see

Comment: i have imported it : from csv import DictReader

Comment: Can you please explain a little, how it works. Want to learn

Comment: @Sainita `DictReader` it makes the file data as object which can be readable. There is proper description about [DictReader](https://www.kite.com/python/docs/csv.DictReader) given on kite

Comment: Thanks You so much for multiple solutions . Heads Up !

Answer (score 2):

As you have both the item and the description in your DataFrame you could iterate over the complete row. Then `row` will hold a Series with the fields `'title'` and `'description'` which you can access as shown below

```
for _, row in df.iterrows() : 
    ref.push().set({
        'title' : row['title'],
        'description' : row['description']
    })
```

The `_` is necessary as `DataFrame.iterrows()` returns the number of the row as well and you ignore it with this.

Comment: Can you please explain a little, how it works. Want to learn

Comment: I think there are several places where this is already explained very well. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas or the (excellent) pandas User guide https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/basics.html#iteration